# Working with Euler's Constant...

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I prove that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} > \ln (n+1)$?

Or

Maybe it is better to prove that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \ln (n+1)$ >0?

Any advice would be a big help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any Euler constant here. Please update the title.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the rectangle $[n, n+1], \frac{1}{n}$ and compare $\int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{dx}{x}$ and the area of the rectangle.